# Is the F-4 visa of the Republic of Korea considered permanent residency (OECD PR) for visa application purposes?

Tags: visas, south-korea

For example, if a country provides holders of OECD PR special treatment (say simplification or exemption), would an F-4 visa of the Republic of Korea be considered such PR?

Answer (score 7):

No. The F-4 visa is valid two years only. Unlike PR, it is temporary, and has to be renewed.